# Hiding the MOTD when creating a cluster with `makeClusterPSOCK`

Tags: r, linux, ssh, cluster-computing, future

I'm starting a cluster with the following call from an Rscript:

```
cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(
  workers = workers,
  verbose = FALSE,
  ...
)
```

where `workers` are hostnames of various nodes in our cluster. When doing this, the console is spammed with the MOTD warning me about proper use consisting of too many lines. I'm not interested in reading this warning more than once (ever). How can I create this cluster in a way that doesn't show these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can pass arguments to the ssh call that opens the SSH connection by using the argument `rshopts` as follows:

```
cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(
  workers = workers,
  verbose = FALSE,
  rshopts = '-q', 
  ...
)
```

This starts ssh in quiet mode:

> `-q      Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.`

which does the trick for me.

Comment: Easier than expected.